# Building iOS framework missing architecture armv7s and x86_64 on fat file

Tags: ios, frameworks

I'm building my own framework by following the guide on site

[Create a framework for iOS - RayWenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios)

It works well, but when I integrate the framework on test project, it catches error as "undefined symbol for architecture arm64". When I check the supported architectures by the command

```
<myframework>.framework xcrun lipo -info <myframework>
```

it misses 2 architectures armv7s and x86_64

Here is my run script on Aggregate target

```
set -e

# If we're already inside this script then die
if [ -n "$RW_MULTIPLATFORM_BUILD_IN_PROGRESS" ]; then
exit 0
fi
export RW_MULTIPLATFORM_BUILD_IN_PROGRESS=1

RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}
RW_INPUT_STATIC_LIB="lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a"
RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

function build_static_library {
    # Will rebuild the static library as specified
    #     build_static_library sdk
    xcrun xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" \
    -target "${TARGET_NAME}" \
    -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" \
    -sdk "${1}" \
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
    BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" \
    OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" \
    BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" \
    SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}" $ACTION
}

function make_fat_library {
    # Will smash 2 static libs together
    #     make_fat_library in1 in2 out
    xcrun lipo -create "${1}" "${2}" -output "${3}"
}

# 1 - Extract the platform (iphoneos/iphonesimulator) from the SDK name
if [[ "$SDK_NAME" =~ ([A-Za-z]+) ]]; then
RW_SDK_PLATFORM=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
echo "Could not find platform name from SDK_NAME: $SDK_NAME"
exit 1
fi

# 2 - Extract the version from the SDK
if [[ "$SDK_NAME" =~ ([0-9]+.*$) ]]; then
RW_SDK_VERSION=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
echo "Could not find sdk version from SDK_NAME: $SDK_NAME"
exit 1
fi

# 3 - Determine the other platform
if [ "$RW_SDK_PLATFORM" == "iphoneos" ]; then
RW_OTHER_PLATFORM=iphonesimulator
else
RW_OTHER_PLATFORM=iphoneos
fi

# 4 - Find the build directory
if [[ "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR" =~ (.*)$RW_SDK_PLATFORM$ ]]; then
RW_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${RW_OTHER_PLATFORM}"
else
echo "Could not find other platform build directory."
exit 1
fi

# Build the other platform.
build_static_library "${RW_OTHER_PLATFORM}${RW_SDK_VERSION}"

# If we're currently building for iphonesimulator, then need to rebuild
#   to ensure that we get both i386 and x86_64
if [ "$RW_SDK_PLATFORM" == "iphonesimulator" ]; then
build_static_library "${SDK_NAME}"
fi

# Join the 2 static libs into 1 and push into the .framework
make_fat_library "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_INPUT_STATIC_LIB}" \
"${RW_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_INPUT_STATIC_LIB}" \
"${RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION}/Versions/A/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}"

# Ensure that the framework is present in both platform's build directories
cp -a "${RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION}/Versions/A/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}" \
"${RW_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}"

# Copy the framework to the user's desktop
ditto "${RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION}" "${HOME}/Desktop/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
```

I suppose the build error when integrating framework to test project causes by the missing architecture when building framework

Comment: any news on this, I am missing only armv7s.

Comment: @Sanandrea, on Architectures I add 2 architecture armv7 and armv7s, and on Valid Architecture, I add all, including armv7, armv7s, arm64, i386 and x86_64. just solve my case

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, except for some reason it only wants to produce i386 and x86_64 in the final fat file

Answer (score 7):

Solved, in my case: in the main target (RWUIControls, if you refer to Ray W. post) I added manually the armv7s architecture.

See screenshot below:

[image]

if I run the command from the terminal:

```
xcrun lipo -info RWUIControls
```

inside the framework folder now I get:

```
Architectures in the fat file: RWUIControls are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy only change the iOS Development Target in the project Info.

In my case I had selected iOS 13 then I changed it to iOS 10 and now I have those Archs -> armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64.

These are the Architectures depending on the iOS device.

armv64: iPhoneX, iPhone 5s-8, iPad Air — iPad Pro
armv7 : iPhone3Gs-5c, iPad WIFI(4th gen)
armv6 : iPhone — iPhone3G
the above if for real devices
i386 : 32-bit simulator
x86_64 : 64-bit simulator